# What is the idea of including the hash value of the "Master Login Password" in the web service call

Tags: web-services, authentication, hash

I am reading a documentation about how to call an application web service , they say for security reason to include the Master Login Username & Master Login Password in the web service call, such as

```
/jw/web/json/workflow/process/start/testcall?j_username=kermit&hash=9449B5ABCFA9AFDA36B801351ED3DF66&loginAs=john
```

but this raised a question in my mind what is the idea of hashing the password? since i am displaying the password hash value that will be matched against the hash value in the database?

**So it is still unsecure to expose the password hash value  if the server is expecting the  password hash value also** !!!  ? i mean at the end the value of the password is visible either as a hash value  or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. I should only use the

```
/jw/web/json/workflow/process/start/testcall?j_username=kermit&hash=9449B5ABCFA9AFDA36B801351ED3DF66&loginAs=john
```

At the server side level and not using javaScript, so i will not expose sensitive data.